# Nuxt not serving 404 but nginix is

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js

I've just uploaded my `nuxt.js` site with pre-rendered HTML in `universal mode`, However the server is serving the 404 errors as I'm getting the server with "An error occurred" from `nginix`.

I'm using Docker with `nginix` server.

How can I get my server to let `nuxt.js` handle the routing and serve the errors?

Comment: What does your NGINX configuration look like? Have you checked this guide? https://nuxtjs.org/faq/nginx-proxy/

Comment: Thanks...I don't have server admin to check.....but i'll need to set reverse proxy on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Its good to use a reverse proxy before your application, here i show you my nginx nuxt configuration.

In my case the configuration is under `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.

```
server {

  server_name homepage.com www.homepage.com;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/homepage.at/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/homepage.at/privkey.pem;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

   }

   location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|ico)$ {
     root /root/AutoProjekt/static;
     expires 1y;
     add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
  }



}
server {

  server_name homepage.com www.homepage.com;
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

On the top define your website name.
The port for HTTPS is 443 so you need to listen to it.
You can get the two certificates easely wih https://certbot.eff.org/ just follow the instruction.

At location you tell nginx where your nuxt projekt is in my case its at `/`
Important here is to pass the client to your application with is running in my case at port 3000.

The next `location` isnt necessary its optional. In my application i can upload images and the problem witch i have is that my images doesnt have a `Cache-Control` header that signals the browser to cache it. However its not essential for you here.

And the last one you listen to the port `80` witch is HTTP. There you redirect your incoming request to HTTPS.

After making changes always test for syntax errors with `nginx -t` and if its ok then restart your nginx with `systemctl restart nginx`

I also suggest to use `pm2` https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

`npm i pm2 -g`

Its a production process manager that handles all your node.js processes. The problem witch you get if you just start the application with `npm start` is that your application stop to work if you close for examply PuTTy.

Usually you start the application with `npm start` but with pm2 you can start it like this:

`pm2 start npm --name MyCoolApp -- start`

You should see now your app with status online. To stop it type in `pm2 stop MyCoolApp` and for run obviously `pm2 start MyCoolApp`